# sql where clause only to be included if case when

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I was wondering if it's possible to run a script for multiple Clients where I can add extra where clauses when I'm running for the specified Client, without having to rewrite the basic script multiple times?

Eg. basic script is

```
SELECT Status, count(distinct T1.AccountNo)
FROM Orders (nolock), Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Orders.AccountNo = Accounts .AccountNo  
AND date between '1 Oct 2011' and '31 Oct 2011'
GROUP BY Status
```

But when I run for Client A I would like to include the extra criteria

```
AND Accounts.Role IN ('User','Admin')
AND Accounts.Active= 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server, you can use HOST_NAME() as follows:

```
SELECT Status, count(distinct T1.AccountNo)
FROM Orders (nolock), Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Orders.AccountNo = Accounts .AccountNo  
AND date between '1 Oct 2011' and '31 Oct 2011'
AND ((HOST_NAME() <> 'ClientA') OR (Accounts.Role IN ('User') AND Accounts.Active= 'Y'))
GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Status, count(distinct T1.AccountNo)
FROM Orders (nolock), Accounts (NOLOCK)
WHERE Orders.AccountNo = Accounts .AccountNo  
AND date between '1 Oct 2011' and '31 Oct 2011'
AND CASE WHEN Client = 'A' THEN Accounts.Role ELSE 'User' END IN ('User', 'Admin')
AND CASE WHEN Client = 'A' THEN Accounts.Active ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'
GROUP BY Status
```

Comment: Hi,I've just update my script for "AND Accounts.Role IN ('User')" and changed to "AND Accounts.Role IN ('User','Admin')". Do I just change the bit... ELSE 'User','Admin' END IN ('User','Admin')?

Comment: Hi I've just tried but it's not looking at the "extra" criteria. When Client = 'A' I want it to filter by Accounts.Role and Account.Active. But in the script provided doesn't it read when Client = 'A' then All Accounts.Roles otherwise just Accounts.Role in ('User'), I would like it the other way around. Will it be THEN Accounts.Role in ('User','Admin') ELSE Accounts.Role END???

Comment: No, the way I wrote it is correct. If the Client is A, it is going to check to see if Accounts.Role is in 'User', otherwise it'll see if User is in User (i.e. always true). To your original comment, you only need to change the IN portion. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this in Stored Procedures a lot when a parameter is not needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE ((@myvariable IS NULL OR @myvariable = mycolumn))
```

Unfortunately this usually causes a scan since it may or may not short circuit.

The other example that I was going to post is the same as Derek Kromm's.

Lastly you can use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - people either love it or hate it.

Comment: My assumption is that we're talking about SQL Server.